# TypeError: $(...).maxlength is not a function - maxlength plugin counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use JQuery `maxlength()` in a `<textarea>` but I'm getting an error in the firefox console.

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(function () {
        // some jquery scripts working ok
        $('#desc').maxlength();
    });
</script>

<textarea id="desc" maxlength="1000" name="description"></textarea>
```

I'm using JQuery (stable) 2.1.4 version. Where's the problem?

Edit: It's an external plugin: http://pioul.fr/jquery-maxlength

http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/ysC7L/

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: There's no such method in core jquery. What makes you thing there is?
Also, don't use phrases like "last (stable) version", just mention the  real version - otherwise your claim will soon become irrelevant.

Comment: 1. `$("#desc")` is not an element. It is an array-like list. 2. `.maxlength` is not a function. There's no such thing and randomly putting things together usually won't work at all.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's an external plugin. I'll leave the website and a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery.fn.attr(attributeName)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) will return you the value of whatever attribute name:

```
$("#desc").attr("maxlength")
```

You can also set attribute using [`jQuery.fn.attr(attributeName, value)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value)

```
$("#desc").attr("name_of_element","element_value")
```

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef what do you mean?

Comment: I just write the same answer after you with 12sec  so I said no need for it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you load your scripts in the right order:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-fn-maxlength.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#desc').maxlength();
  });
</script>
```